# Map a Stream<T> to a Map<T, Long> that is counting?

Tags: java, mapping, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Stream<T>`, is it possible to generate a `Map<T, Long>` that increases count by one for every element? I'd also like if it could reverse the `T, Long` to `Long, T`, before storing it in a `Map`, example input/output:

Example contents of `Stream<String>`:

```
kgj
def
dgh
```

Wanted output for first question:

```
(kgj, 1)
(def, 2)
(dgh, 3)
```

Wanted output in the end:

```
(1, kgj)
(2, def)
(3, dgh)
```

What I have so far, for a `Stream<VertexData>`:

```
    primitives.stream()
            .flatMap(primitive -> primitive.getVertexData().stream())
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()))
            .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("k = " + k + " / v = " + v));
```

This currently turns a `Stream<Primitive>` into a `Stream<VertexData>` with distinct elements, and then to a `Map<VertexData, Long>` that *counts occurences*, which is **not** what I want, as I want it to *keep on counting at every element that passes*.

Is there a way to do what I ask?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8

Comment: @assylias I'd say it provides a workaround and thanks for guiding me to that question, however it's not a definitive answer, hence why you posted it as a comment I think.

Comment: What would you like your output for the first question to be when using inputs with repetions (such as ["abc", "def", "abc"])?

Comment: @jpvee It should only count distinct elements, (I had that already in *what I have so far*), with streams it is very easy to get a stable distinct with `list.stream().distinct()`.

Comment: In scala I would just `x.zipWithIndex` and for the second: `x.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2,x._1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is write your own `Collector` that does the counting for you on the elements encountered. Something like the following works:

```
  Stream<String> strings = Stream.of("kgj", "def", "dgh");

  strings.distinct().collect(Collector.of(
          HashMap::new,
          (BiConsumer<Map<String, Long>, String>) (map, str) -> {
            map.put(str, Long.valueOf(map.size() + 1));
          },
          (left, right) -> {
            long s = left.size();
            right.entrySet().forEach(e -> left.put(e.getKey(),
                                                   Long.valueOf(
                                                           e.getValue()
                                                                   .longValue()
                                                           + s)));
            return left;
          })).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("k = " + k + " / v = " + v));
```

Note that the (somewhat complex) combiner (third argument to `Collector.of()` is needed in cases where the stream is processed in parallel).

Comment: Any clue what this would do to the performance? And is there a way to 'disable' parallel processing, as you can never count in parallel anyway... Or can you?

Answer (score 1):

Inspiried by @jpvee I made a `Collector` that answers the last subquestion of the question and intends to be somewhat more clear aswell:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Map<Long, T>> indexing() {
    return Collector.of(
            HashMap::new,
            (map, t) -> map.put(Long.valueOf(map.size() + 1), t),
            (left, right) -> {
                final long size = left.size();
                right.forEach((k, v) -> left.put(k + size, v));
                return left;
            },
            Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT
    );
}
```

What this does is:

- Operated on a `Stream<T>`, it returns a `Map<Long, T>` that indexes `T` with the encounter order of the stream.
- It uses `Collector.of`, which in normal words accepts the following:

  - A *supplier* for the `Map`.
  - An *accumulator* that adds one element to the `Map`.
  - A *combiner* that combines two `Map`s that possibly came from concurrent access.
  - A list of *charasteristics*.

So what I have provided is:

- `Supplier<R>`: A new `HashMap`.
- `BiConsumer<R, T>`: A function that takes the map and adds a new element.
- `BinaryOperator<R>`: A function that combines two maps.
- `Collector.Charasteristics`: The charasterics for this method, which allows concurrent execution.

Comment: Kind of an interesting use of collectors, but it ends up being *O(n log n)* in time. The reason is that each merge copies exactly half the elements, and there are *log n* levels in the merge tree. This could be run in parallel, but sufficiently large *n* will swamp any parallel speedup.