# Reading words from file at line index

Tags: java, file

What is the best way to read words from file knowing the line index?
I want to read each word in the file and check if contains only digits. If it doesn't I want to print the word index and line index.

I'm currently using this, but I wonder if there is a way to do it without 2 loops.

```
private static void validateNumber ( String fileName )
{

    try ( BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader ( fileName ) ) )
    {

        String line = null;
        int lineIndex = -1;

        while ( ( line = reader.readLine ( ) ) != null )
        {
            lineIndex++;

            String [ ] words = line.trim ( ).split ( "[\\s]+" );

            for ( int i = 0; i < words.length; i++ )
            {
                System.out.println("Word " + i " at line " + lineIndex); 
            }

        }

    } catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace ( );
    } catch ( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace ( );
    }

}
```

Comment: you want read words at certain line ?

Comment: Do you mean you only want to read line 10 for example?

Comment: I want to read words at all lines knowing the line index.

Comment: Regex? You could use regex to get all words without running a loop.

Comment: For reference, [codereview.se](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is more suited for questions regarding code improvement.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use 2 loops you can read the whole text then split on the "\n" character: `String[] lines = text.split("\n");`
Now you have an array of every line and you can retrieve any line by indexing the array. For example, line 5 is `lines[4]`

Comment: I dont think this answers his question

Comment: My question was not complete.
I want to read each word in the file and check if contains only digits. If it doesn't I want to print the word index and line index.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to read words from file knowing the line index?

From Java 8 you can use the Stream API:

```
long lineIndex = 3; // e.g.: fourth line

String line = Files.lines(Paths.get("myfile.txt"))
                    .skip(lineIndex)
                    .findFirst()
                    .get();
```

But since you need to check every single line and you want to print the line number, the while loop is your best option as Java 8 streams don't have an index (find out why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789413/what-are-the-reasons-for-not-having-an-index-in-java-8-streams)).