# Find all the indexes of an item within a list using stream API

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

I am trying sequential search using Java 8 streams and lambda expressions. Here is my code

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10, 6, 16, 46, 5, 16, 7);
int search = 16;
list.stream().filter(p -> p == search).forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.println(list.indexOf(e)));
```

```
Output: 2
        2
```

I know `list.indexOf(e)` always prints the index of the first occurrence. How do I print all the indexes?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with this kind of structure. Once you've filtered, you've lost the index information. If you did print indexes after this, you'd get indexes within the filtered list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18552005/1407656 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/22793006/1407656

Comment: @Tom what is query in the given post. when i try this giving compilation error at query.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For a start, using Lambdas is not the solution to all problems... but, even then, as a for loop, you would write it:

```
List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (search == list.get(i).intValue()) {
        // found value at index i
        results.add(i);
    }
}
```

Now, there's nothing particularly wrong with that, but note that the critical aspect here is the index, not the value. The index is the input, and the output of the 'loop'.

As a stream::

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10, 6, 16, 46, 5, 16, 7);
int search = 16;
int[] indices = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .filter(i -> list.get(i) == search)
                .toArray();
System.out.printf("Found %d at indices %s%n", search, Arrays.toString(indices));
```

Produces output:

```
Found 16 at indices [2, 5]
```

Comment: Is there exra %n at the end of printf function, three subsitutes but two params was provided?

Comment: @Whome - the `%n` adds an OS specific line-terminator (a well-behaved `\n`). It does not need a matching substitution value. (See "Line Separator [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) )

Answer (score 1):

To find the indexes of **every** value in a `List` as a `Map`, we can use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) of indexes with [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-).

```java
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
//...
final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> indexMap = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(list::get));
//{16=[2, 5], 5=[4], 6=[1], 7=[6], 10=[0], 46=[3]}
//Map of item value to List of indices at which it occurs in the original List
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/IuDcUD)

Now, if you want to get the list of indices for `search`, you can do so as follows:

```
System.out.println(indexMap.get(search));
```