# How to find a first even integer in ArrayList<Integer>?

Tags: java, arraylist

In this method I am trying to find a first even integer in an `ArrayList` (for further use).

However, when I am calling the method I get -1. As much as I know, this means that there is no integer in the list (but there actually are).

Here is the code:

```
public static int rangeBetweenEvens(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    int firstEven = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
         firstEven = list.indexOf((i) % 2 == 0);

    }

    return  firstEven;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to return an index or a value?

Comment: Can you be more explicit with your question

Answer (score 6):

You are attempting to find the first occurrence of `(i) % 2 == 0`, however, this isn't doing what you think it is.  This expression is evaluated as a boolean expression -- `true` if `i` is even and `false` if it's odd.  In the first iteration, `i` is 0 (even), but `true` is not found in the list, because integers exist there, so you are returning the result of `indexOf` -- `-1`.

Using `indexOf` is a mistake here, because that searches the list for a specific value.  Instead, use `get(i)` to retrieve the current value, and test it to see if it's even.  If it is, return that current index, else keep searching.  Return `-1` if not found.

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf` returns the **index** a value was found in, not the value in the index, which you could retrieve with `get`, or even better, use the enhanced `for` loop syntax:

```
public static Integer firstEven(List<Integer> list) {
    for (Integer curr : list) {
         if (curr % 2 == 0) {
             return curr;
         }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note, by the way, that Java 8's streaming syntax can help you do this much more elegantly

```
public static Integer firstEven(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating with the index not with the value. Do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    if(list.get(i) %2 == 0){
         return list.get(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`indexOf(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) accepts an element and tries to find it's index in your collection, so you can't get a condition in there as it will search for `true|false` inside your list which isn't there

You can check and break from the loop when you get the index like :

```
public static int rangeBetweenEvens(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

        int firstEven = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
                if(list.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
                        firstEven = list.indexOf(i);
                }

                break;

        }

        return firstEven;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method is written incorrectly. Instead of indexOf you should be using get(i). Ie. the for loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
     if(list.get(i) % 2 == 0)
        return i;
}
```

Comment: what should return this code if there's not even integer in the list?

Comment: I imagine if the author wanted to keep original contract there should be a "return -1" at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the advanced for loop:

```
for(int i : list){
if(i%2==0)
return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26179182/2718027) useful. Based on that, to find the index of the first even number (or return -1 if none found), you do:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(11, 10, 1, 42, 5, 11, 7);
    int firstEven = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .filter(i -> (list.get(i) % 2 == 0))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(-1);

    System.out.printf("first even at %d", firstEven);
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.indexOf((i) % 2 == 0);`  condition inside returns Boolean. Most likely that not what you expect.

Your code should be looks like following:

```
firstEven = -1;
lastEven = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if ( list.get(i) %2 == 0) {
        if (firstEven == -1)  firstEven = list.get(i);
        lastEven = list.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the problem is that within the same method i will have to find index of the last even number. What suggestions would you have for that?

Answer (score 0):

Java -8 way of doing it (I say start using Java -8 :P).

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1,3,4,5,2);
Optional<Integer> oi = l.stream().filter(i -> i%2==0).findFirst();
if (oi.isPresent())
System.out.println(oi.get());
```

Or Like chris says, use :

```
l.stream().filter(i -> i%2==0).findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Alternatively, `.findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println)` (or whatever method you want to call on it).

Comment: @chris - edited the answer.. Donno how I missed it :(. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
(i) % 2 == 0
```

This will return either true or false. And there are no true or false as index.
Try this:

```
public static int rangeBetweenEvens(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

        int firstEven = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
         if (list.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
              firstEven = list.get(i);
              break;
         }

    }

    return  firstEven;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a try at this...

```
for (int i : list)
{
     if(i % 2 == 0)
        return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use This....

```
import  java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstEvenNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String numbers;
        System.out.println("Enter numbers separated by coma without spaces:");
        numbers = sc.nextLine();
        String[] splited = numbers.split(",");
        sc.close();
        int [] array = Arrays.asList(splited).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
        outerloop:
        for (int num : array){
            if (num%2 == 0){
                System.out.println(num);
                break outerloop;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

*with lambda function avoiding the % modulo operator*

```
Function<List<Integer>, Integer> firstEven = ints -> {
  Integer rslt;
  ListIterator<Integer> it = ints.listIterator();
  while( it.hasNext() )
    if( ((rslt = it.next()) & 1) == 0 )
      return( rslt );
  return( null );
};
```

`firstEven.apply( list );`