# Stream<String> Only inputting the last line from Files.lines()

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

In my code I have

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.forName("Cp1252"))
                .filter(k -> k != "")
                .forEach(m -> hashmap.put(LocalDateTime.MIN, m));
```

To read the lines from a file called "`info`" (`fileName`).

```
1
2
3
4
5
(blank line)
```

However, when scanning the HashMap it tells me that only the last line has been inserted using this code:

```
int x = 0;
for (HashMap.Entry<LocalDateTime, String> s : hashmap.entrySet()) {
    x++;
    System.out.println(hashmap.size() + ": " + x + ": " + s.getValue());
}
```

That prints out `1: 1: 5` only once.

Comment: `.filter(k -> k != "")` don't compare Strings with `==` or `!=`. Use `equals` (or negate `!` result).

Comment: @Pshemo Missed that, thanks.

Comment: …or just use `.filter(k -> ! k.isEmpty())`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your code snippet puts all lines under the same key into the `HashMap`. This code

```
.forEach(m -> hashmap.put(LocalDateTime.MIN, m));
```

takes each line from the file, and puts it at the key equal to `LocalDateTime.MIN`. Since `HashMap` cannot contain multiple identical keys, the last item is the only one remaining in the map after `forEach` finishes.

To fix this problem choose a different container, such as a list, or use a different strategy of assigning keys to lines that you read from the file.

Comment: Any chance you know how to I could do an iteration counter in this format so I can set them as different keys?

Comment: @Rob Unfortunately, Java does not offer an easy way of doing it ([here is a relevant Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18552005/335858)). You could use some of the tricks from that Q&A, but it's not ideal.

Comment: AtomicInteger worked. It's sloppy, but it works. Thanks!