# How to use stream to do one thing on elements not-in-index-range and another on yes-in-range?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This question

*[Is there a concise way to iterate over a stream with indices in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8)*

describes how to drive one stream based on another stream of indexes. My goal is to take an array of strings

```
one two three four five six seven eight
```

and all-cap the elements having an array index between 2 and 5:

```
one two THREE FOUR FIVE SIX seven eight
```

I've figured out how to do this, but my instinct says there should be a more elegant way of going about it. In the below example, the first stream filters out all elements except those in range. It's not directly what I want, of course, but it's similar in how it uses a stream to filter by index-range. The second alters the array elements in place, capitalizing the ones I want.

I don't like how it alters the array in place, and how it requires two streams. Is there a better way?

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class UpperCaseElementsInIndexRangeViaIntStream {

   public static void main(String[] ignored) {
      final String input = "one two three four five six seven eight";
      final int MIN_IDX = 2;
      final int MAX_IDX = 5;
      final String[] splits = input.split(" ");

      //Filter only those in range

      String output = IntStream.range(0, splits.length).
            filter(idx -> MIN_IDX <= idx && idx <= MAX_IDX).
            mapToObj(i -> splits[i]).
            collect(joining(" "));

      System.out.println(output);

      //Change the array in place, capitalizing only those in range

      IntStream.range(0, splits.length).forEach(idx -> {
         final String split = splits[idx];
         splits[idx] = (MIN_IDX <= idx && idx <= MAX_IDX)
                       ? split.toUpperCase() : split;
      });

      output = Arrays.stream(splits).collect(joining(" "));

      System.out.println(output);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
three four five six
one two THREE FOUR FIVE SIX seven eight
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also thought there should be a `map(predicate, functionIfTrue,  functionIfFalse)` kind of method, but there isn't. Instead, use a ternary in your map:

```
final int[] idx = {-1}; // trick to get around "effectively final"
String result = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
   .map(s -> MIN_IDX <= ++idx[0] && idx[0] <= MAX_IDX ? s.toUpperCase() : s)
   .collect(joining(" "));
```

This employs a trick to get the index of the iteration by using a single element array that is itself final, but whose contents are mutable.

---

Some test code:

```
final String input = "one two three four five six seven eight";
final int MIN_IDX = 2;
final int MAX_IDX = 5;
final int[] idx = {-1};
String result = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
    .map(s -> MIN_IDX <= ++idx[0] && idx[0] <= MAX_IDX ? s.toUpperCase() : s)
    .collect(joining(" "));
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
one two THREE FOUR FIVE SIX seven eight
```

Comment: I actually though about adding such `map(predicate, functionIfTrue,  functionIfFalse)` to my StreamEx library, but is there any benefit of such method over ternary operator? Usually ternary is shorter.

Comment: Neat trick with the index. I wonder if there are any consequences doing that. Just the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @aliteralmind, the consequence is that this solution will not work for parallel streams.

Comment: @TagirValeev Any alternatives that can work in parallel then? It seems an IntStream is required. And perhaps two streams, too  :(

Comment: @aliteralmind, single stream is enough (though `input.split(" ")` is still sequential). Posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution without `Stream`. Use [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) to get a view of the range you want as a `List`. Then use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) to transform the elements in place.

```
List<String> all = Arrays.asList(splits);
all.subList(MIN_IDX, MAX_IDX + 1).replaceAll(String::toUpperCase);
// use 'all' as needed
```

Note that the second parameter of `replaceAll` is an exclusive index value.

Comment: Well my goal is to learn streams, so perhaps it not the best question for that purpose. But this is seriously interesting. Can’t believe I never heard of subList before. Seems like its been around since Java 6.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Stream API-based solution which is parallel friendly:

```
final String[] splits = input.split(" ");

String output = IntStream.range(0, splits.length).parallel()
    .mapToObj(idx -> MIN_IDX <= idx && idx <= MAX_IDX ?
              splits[idx].toUpperCase() : splits[idx])
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Note that I'm posting this answer just for the completeness. Streams are not well-suitable for indexed operations. I vote for @SotiriosDelimanolis solution, it's really simple and elegant.

Comment: Learned a lot here, but completely different stuff than I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*functionally similar but more streamlined*

```
IntStream.range( 0, splits.length ).boxed().collect( Collector.of(
    StringBuilder::new,
    (buf, idx) -> buf.append( idx > 0 ? " " : "" ).append(
        idx >= MIN_IDX && idx <= MAX_IDX ? splits[idx].toUpperCase() : splits[idx] ),
    (buf1, buf2) -> buf1 ) ).toString();
```

*streamlined:*
– allocation of only one `StringBuilder`
– the mapping is omitted