# Is it possible to replace a simple java for loop (with index) with java 8 stream

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to have failfast behavior for any unsuccessful response and if all go successful then I return the last successful response as shown in following code.

```
for(int i=0;i<input.size(); i++){
   Data data = service.getData(input.get(i));
   if(data.isSuccessful() && i==input.size()-1){
      return data;
   }else if(!data.isSuccessful()){
    return data;
    }else{
    return null;
  }
 }
```

I tried to replace above mention code with streams but not been able to do so far.Main issue is that 
I am not able to imitate i(index) variable behavior in java8 stream code.

```
resp = input.stream().map((input)->{service.getData()}).filter(
(resp)->{
     if(!resp.isSuccessful())
        return true; 
     else if(resp.isSuccessful() && last resp)//if somehow I figure out last element
        return true;
     else 
        return false;}).findFirst();
```

Comment: First, `i` can never be equal to `input.size()` since `i<input.size()` in the for loop.

Comment: Look at your two variants. Letting aside that it doesn’t work, do you really have the feeling that the second one is an improvement over the `for` loop?

Comment: The loop in the original code only process one element since every code path in the body of the loop returns a value.

Comment: @Holger performance should be the criteria. But my intention was to migrate code to java8

Comment: @All sorry guys for lot of small mistakes. my real intention is plainly written in first line.

Comment: There is no reason why the stream variant should have a better performance than the for loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need for external libraries.

```
return IntStream.range(0, input.size())
.mapToObj(i -> {
    Data data = service.getData(input.get(i));
    if (!data.isSuccessful() || i == input.size() - 1) {
        return Optional.of(data);
    }
    return Optional.<Data>empty();
})
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.findFirst()
.orElse(null);
```

- More information about looping with indices: [Is there a concise way to iterate over a stream with indices in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8)
- Consider returing the `Optional`, rather than the result or `null`

Complete example (compilable):

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Data {
    public boolean isSuccessful() {return false;}
}
class Input {
    public Object get(int i) {return null;}
    public int size() {return 0;}
}
class Service {
    public Data getData(Object object) {return null;}
}
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {method();}

    protected static Optional<Data> method() {
        Input input = new Input();
        Service service = new Service();

        return IntStream.range(0, input.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> {
                    Data data = service.getData(input.get(i));
                    if (!data.isSuccessful() || i == input.size() - 1) {
                        return Optional.of(data);
                    }
                    return Optional.<Data>empty();
                })
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: That what I meant saying "pure Stream API solution would be much uglier".

Comment: Hmm, while this certainly answers the OP's question, I feel that from a subjective point of view this solution shouldn't be preferred over an imperative one, style-wise.

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you actually want the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
    Data data = service.getData(input.get(i));
    if (!data.isSuccessful() || i == input.size() - 1) {
        return data;
    }
}
return null;
```

The shortest lambda-based solution I can propose involves the [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) library:

```
return Seq.seq(input)
          .map(service::getData)
          .limitWhileClosed(Data::isSuccessful)
          .reduce((a, b) -> b)
          .orElse(null);
```

The essential part here is `limitWhileClosed` method which takes the input element while the condition holds, but also includes the first element which violates the condition. After that we use `reduce((a, b) -> b)` to get the last taken element.

The `limitWhileClosed` method is absent in Java-8 Stream API. Java-9 will add the `takeWhile` which is similar, but does not include the violating element. So the pure Stream API solution would be much uglier than plain `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks that will do. I will use jooq library. is it at all beneficial, performance wise to replace this for loop with stream api.

Comment: @bharat9848, you will likely to lose some performance with jOOλ, though if your `server::getData` is expensive, then the performance loss would be relatively insignificant.