# Stream filter and retrieve index of the item in list

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there any fast way to filter a list and get the index of the value?

```
Optional<model> allocated = data.stream().filter(p => "p".equals(p.getType())).findAny();
```

I want to get the indexOf what I found?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963338/stream-way-to-get-index-of-first-element-matching-boolean

Comment: without any library.

Comment: It contains native solutions:) @Alex Rudenko has posted one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IntStream` needs to be used to iterate the indexes:

```
int indexOf = IntStream.range(0, data.size())
    .filter(i -> "p".equals(data.get(i).getType()))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(-1);
```

---

**Update**

It may be worth to implement a generic utility method allowing to search for values of specific field in the object including `null`:

```java
public static <T, V> int indexOf(
    V value, List<T> list, Function<T, V> getter
) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
             .filter(i -> Objects.nonNull(list.get(i)))
             .filter(i -> Objects.equals(
                     value, getter.apply(list.get(i))
             ))
             .findFirst()
             .orElse(-1); 
}
```