# What's the Java 8 equivalent of zipWithIndex method in Scala List?

Tags: collections, java-8

I have a `List` of Integer's as like below.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

I want something like Scala `zipWithIndex()` method in Scala List.

Can we do something similar with `Java-8` FP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip There's no direct way.

Comment: @Tunaki : whatever you referred is zip not zipWithIndex.

Comment: `zipWithIndex` _is_ `zip` added with a Stream of indexes. What you want is in the linked duplicate question. My comment above was a FYI, that's all.