# Using Streams to replace loops

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
boolean found = false;
for (Commit commit : commits.values()) {
    if (commit.getLogMessage().compareTo(commitMessageToSearch) == 0) {
        System.out.println(commit.getSha());
        found = true;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("aksdhlkasj");
}
```

Is there some way to write this succinctly using streams or anything else in Java

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream#filter` along with `Stream#findFirst`.

```
System.out.println(commits.values().stream()
    .filter(commit -> commit.getLogMessage().compareTo(commitMessageToSearch) == 0)
    .findFirst().map(Commit::getSha).orElse("aksdhlkasj"));
```

Comment: Putting the pipeline in the method parameters impairs readability. Use `ifPresent()` or `ifPresentOrElse()` to call `println()` instead.

Comment: @Unmitigated is findFirst required here? As I want to print all the match commits and not only the first on

Comment: @daniel If you need to print all the matches, then do not call `findFirst`.

Comment: Then how `aksdhlkasj` is supposed to be printed if no match is found?

Answer (score 0):

The following options are available:

1. Use `StreamEx` library ([maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/one.util/streamex)) and its quasi-intermediate operation [StreamEx::ifEmpty](https://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#ifEmpty(T...)):

```java
import one.util.streamex.StreamEx;
// ...
String msgSearch = "commit message";
StreamEx.of(commits.values())
        .filter(c -> c.getLogMessage().compareTo(msgSearch) == 0)
        .ifEmpty("no commit message found: " + msgSearch)
        .map(Commit::getSha)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

- Plus: very concise and clean, single run
- Minus: use of a 3rd-party lib

---

2. Check the contents of the stream using short-circuiting match *without redundant collecting into a list just to check if it's empty*

```java
if (commits.values().stream()
    .map(Commit::getLogMessage) // equals should be equivalent to compareTo == 0
    .anyMatch(msgSearch::equals)
) {
    commits.values().stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getLogMessage().compareTo(msgSearch) == 0)
        .map(Commit::getSha)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
} else {
    System.out.println("no commit message found: " + msgSearch);
}
```

- Plus: using standard API (no 3-rd party) without side-effect
- Minuses: too verbose, in the worst case (long list with the matching element in the end) double iteration of the stream

---

3. Use effectively final variable and its setting from the stream as a side effect.

Disclaimer: usage of stateful streams and side effects are [not recommended *in general*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> *The best approach is to avoid stateful behavioral parameters to stream operations entirely...
>
> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.
>
> A small number of stream operations, such as `forEach()` and `peek()`, can **operate only via side-effects; these should be used with care***

Thus, if `AtomicBoolean` is carefully selected as a thread-safe and fast container of a boolean value for `found` flag, which is *only* set to `true` from inside the stream (never reset), the following solution may be offered and the risks of safety and performance are mitigated:

```java
// effectively final and thread-safe container boolean
AtomicBoolean found = new AtomicBoolean(); 

commits.values().stream()
    .filter(c -> c.getLogMessage().compareTo(commitMessageToSearch) == 0)
    .map(Commit::getSha)
    .forEach(sha -> {
        found.set(true); 
        System.out.println(sha);
    });

if (!found.get()) {
    System.out.println("none found");
}
```

- Plus: using standard API (no 3rd-party library), single run, no redundant collection
- Minus: using side-effect, discouraged by purists, just mimics of `for-each` loop

Comment: I am not a downvoter but I most likely know the reason for it. The Stream violates the "no side effects" principle by modifying the state of `AtomicBoolean`. See my question for more information about this topic as I initially used Streams this way before I learned their real purpose and behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977793/is-use-of-atomicinteger-for-indexing-in-stream-a-legit-way

Comment: @Nikolas, I wrote a sort of disclaimer about that, and provided a version without the side effect (which is more verbose than the loop solution).  OPs question was whether this conversion into streams solution is possible, so I tried to prove the feasibility with the mentioned caveats.  The example you referred is using `AtomicInteger`, here the value of `AtomicBoolean` is set to true _once_ and not toggled, so I cannot think of a _real negative_ consequence of this solution which should work for both parallel and sequential streams.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis, I found an interesting solution using `StreamEx::ifEmpty` method though it's a 3-rd party library created to address known limitations of the standard API

Comment: Interesting, however, there is a still solution using the standard JDK Stream.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to print out *all* the occurrences and print some String only in case, there was no item found, I am afraid there is no way other than collecting all the relevant `sha` values into a list and checking for its emptiness using `Optional`:

```
commits.values()
       .stream()
       .filter(commit -> commit.getLogMessage().compareTo(commitMessageToSearch) == 0)
       .map(Commit::getSha)
       .peek(System.out::println)
       .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Optional::of))
       .filter(List::isEmpty)
       .ifPresent(emptyList -> System.out.println("aksdhlkasj"));
```

Although the intermediate output `Optional<List<?>>` is against common sense, it helps the further processing using `Optinal` and comfortably handling the case the list is empty.

However, this form is in my opinion more readable:

```
List<String> shaList = commits.values()
        .stream()
        .filter(commit -> commit.getLogMessage().compareTo(commitMessageToSearch) == 0)
        .map(Commit::getSha)
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
if (shaList.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("aksdhlkasj");
}
```

Comment: This is actually similar to existing answer by @Unmitigated and it does not print _all_ matching SHAs as in the loop solution.  Maybe someday a method to handle/log an empty stream will finally be added to Stream API to get rid of this clumsiness (e.g., like `forEachOrEmpty` accepting two consumers).

Comment: @AlexRudenko It seems like @Unmitigated had the same understanding of the question but my answer was different anyway. I initially thought the OP missed a `break;`. Now I understand the question and edited my answer. Please, take a look if you are interested.