# Convert a list to list of list using java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list and a batch size. I need to split it into a list of lists where each list has a maximum size of batch size preferably using java8 Stream API.

One important condition is, if I have an empty list `[]`, I need to get `[[]]`.

I am doing this

```
final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
List<List<Integer>> result = listToSplit.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / batchSize))
    .values();
```

But for empty list, it gives `[[null]]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a common Java utility to break a list into batches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026885/is-there-a-common-java-utility-to-break-a-list-into-batches)

Comment: You can always add another line like `result = result.isEmpty()?List.of(List.of()):result;`. BTW your code wouldn't compile since result of `map.values()` is `Collection<V>` not `List<V>`. Also after correcting that to store result in `Collection<List<Integer>>` I can't reproduce "But for empty list, it gives [[null]]". For empty list I am getting `[]` not `[null]`.

Comment: If you know that `listToSplit` is null then use it as a base case and set the result as null. Stream process only when `listToSplit` is not null and not empty. 

Btw, I have used the Lists.partition() method of Guava library and it works perfectly. I would suggest to use the same.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that does not help with empty list

Comment: Then add a special case. It is against idiom to return a list with one empty list because it is not flattened. No library will give you that result unless you add a special case yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Few notes first:

1. The hack using `AtomicInteger` or `int[0]` is familiar to me since I have already asked 2 questions regarding it years ago when I started using Streams:

   - [How to increment a value in Java Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304842/how-to-increment-a-value-in-java-stream)
   - [Is use of AtomicInteger for indexing in Stream a legit way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977793/is-use-of-atomicinteger-for-indexing-in-stream-a-legit-way)
2. As I got more familiar with the core principles of Stream API I realized they should be treated a bit differently than a typical for-loops although you still use `IntStream` that might be close to a procedural `for-loop` construct. Don't violate the [Side-effect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) principle using Stream API.
3. One more thing to remind before we get to a solution is that `Collectors.groupingBy` is a collector resulting in a `Map` and the subsequent call of [`Map.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) returns `Collection<List<Integer>>` instead of `List<List<Integer>>`.
4. A final note is a reminder, that the solution for an empty input list is not compatible with the behavior with a list that can be perfectly chunked (a list of 15 elements split to lists by 5 elements). So, if an empty array results in `[[]]`, then the result `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[]]` of a list `1,2,3,4,5,6` with `batchSize=3` is not acceptable but likely generated with a simple non-branched approach.

With regard to what was said above, you might conclude to this solution, that is not elegant though:

```
int max = (int) Math.ceil((double) listToSplit.size() / batchSize);   // number of chunks

List<List<Integer>> result;

if (listToSplit.isEmpty()) {
    result = Arrays.asList(Collections.emptyList());          // results in [[]] if empty
} else {
    result = IntStream.range(0, max)
        .map(i -> i * batchSize)                              // initial indices
        .mapToObj(i -> listToSplit.subList(                   // find a sublist
            i, Math.min(i + batchSize, listToSplit.size())))  // .. from i*b to (i+1)*b 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());                        // as List<List<Integer>>
}
```

The conclusion is to stick with the old but gold `for-loop` for such use-case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Used `IntStream` and `list.subList`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ListOfList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> listToSplit = new ArrayList<>();
//        listToSplit.add(1);
//        listToSplit.add(1);
//        listToSplit.add(1);
//        listToSplit.add(1);
        double batchSize = 3;

        int loops = Math.max(1,(int) Math.ceil(listToSplit.size()/batchSize));
        final List<List<Integer>> collect = IntStream.iterate(-1, i -> (int) (i + batchSize)).limit(loops)
                .mapToObj(id -> {
                    int actualCounter  = id+1;
                    int finalLength = (int) Math.min(listToSplit.size(),actualCounter + batchSize);
                    return listToSplit.subList(actualCounter, finalLength);
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(collect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a third-party library, you can use [`Collectors2.chunk()`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collector/Collectors2.html#chunk-int-) from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) with a Java Stream.

```
@Test
public void chunk()
{
    List<Integer> listToSplit = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

    List<MutableList<Integer>> chunks = listToSplit.isEmpty() ?
            Lists.mutable.with(Lists.mutable.empty()) :
            listToSplit.stream().collect(Collectors2.chunk(3));

    List<List<Integer>> expected = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3),
            Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6),
            Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9),
            Arrays.asList(10));
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, chunks);
}
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.