# Java Stream - How to add counter i to nth value of the stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, counter

How can I add the counter value to every nth item while iterating though a Stream?

Here is my simplest code:

```
Stream.of("a1","a2","a3")
    .map(x -> x + "counterValue")
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

As I am adding "counterValue" string with every `n`th item, what I want to achieve is to add the `i`th value with every nth element.

The current program gives the output as `a1counterValue`.

I want the output as `a10`. 0 mean the index of that element.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: What is the i'th value?

Comment: At least for me it is not exactly clear, what you are trying to achieve. Can you give an example showing input and desired output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18552005/3788176 the easiest way is to iterate over a stream of indices, then you can count "every nth item". But it depends on the source of your stream as to whether you can refer to its element by index, or if you need to zip the two streams together.

Comment: @AndyTurner I checked this link previously. But i don't want to use IntStream.range...

Comment: You need the index, so you will _need_ something like `Intstream.range` to track the index if you don't want to use a shared mutable value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 List<String> input = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
 IntStream.range(0, input.size())
      .mapToObj(i -> input.get(i) + i)
      .collect(Collectors.toList()) // [one0, two1]
```

Comment: Is there any alternate without using IntStream.range?

Comment: @KaranVerma when you iterate internally over a Steam you are iterating over it's elements, not indexes. streams in general have no notion on indexes, so the answer is : no, no other way.

Comment: @KaranVerma u do know you can accept an answer if it actually helped you right?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate using index by using `IntStream` as shown below:

```
String[] arr = {"a1","a2","a3"};
int lentgh = arr.length;
IntStream.of(0, lentgh).
    mapToObj(((int i) -> i + arr[i])).findFirst().
     ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: There is no need for extraneous braces. You can simply use `mapToObj(i -> i + arr[i])`