# Convert a LinkedList to ArrayList for faster concurrent iterating

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, linked-list

I am well-aware of the costs of iterating `LinkedList` with an external index (`for`loop). Looking into the source code for the `ListIterator` returned by `LinkedList#listIterator`, I notice that it significantly speeds up the process by keeping track of the node it is currently using.

However, I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926920/java-8-extracting-a-pair-of-arrays-out-of-a-streampair/41929197#41929197), which was basically about iterating over two or more lists simultaneously, but needed to do so while keeping track of an index to transfer values to an array. In my mind, this made the use of iterators slightly redundant and more prone to human error, as individual declarations were necessary for each iterator, on top of looping and calling every single `next` method. This is why I tried avoiding the iterator-loop combo. Here is a possible solution to the problem:

```
List<Integer> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
int[] combined = new int[(listOne.size() < listTwo.size() ? listOne.size() : listTwo.size())];
for (int i = 0; i < combined.length; i++) {
    combined[i] = listOne.get(i) + listTwo.get(i);
}
```

This is fine for `ArrayList`, but it would be a rather slow operation with `LinkedList`.

One possible solution would be to use the conversion constructor of `ArrayList` to get all the references from a `LinkedList`:

```
//convert linkedlists to arraylists
ArrayList<Integer> arrayListOne = new ArrayList<>(listOne);
ArrayList<Integer> arrayListTwo = new ArrayList<>(listTwo);
//iterate with an efficient get() operation
for (int i = 0; i < combined.length; i++) {
    combined[i] = listOne.get(i) + listTwo.get(i);
}
```

Since this would only call the iterator of each `LinkedList`once, and then use the more efficient `ArrayList#get` method, is this a viable solution? Would the overhead from the conversion negate the efficiency gain? Are there any other downsides to this method?

Comment: @MouseEvent hence the size check on `combined` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] iterating over two or more lists simultaneously, but needed to do so while keeping track of an index to transfer values to an array, therefore preventing the use of iterators.

Just because you *also* need an index, doesn't mean you can't use an `Iterator`, so the *"preventing the use of iterators"* is an entirely incorrect assertion.

You're just doing a simple 3-way parallel iteration (2 iterators and 1 index):

```
List<Integer> listOne = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> listTwo = new LinkedList<>();
int[] combined = new int[Math.min(listOne.size(), listTwo.size())];
Iterator<Integer> iterOne = listOne.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> iterTwo = listTwo.iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < combined.length; i++) {
    combined[i] = iterOne.next() + iterTwo.next();
}
```

---

**UPDATE** *(to answer specific questions)*

> Since this would only call the iterator of each `LinkedList` once, and then use the more efficient ArrayList#get method, is this a viable solution?

Yes, it's definitely a more viable solution. As the lists gets bigger, the exponential response time of `get(index)` for a `LinkedList` makes using `get()` a really bad solution.

> Would the overhead from the conversion negate the efficiency gain?

No. Even at small list sizes, the sequential search performance of `get(index)` on a `LinkedList` will far outweigh any performance loss from the copying of the list.

> Are there any other downsides to this method?

Copying the list first increases the memory requirements, and requires an extra (*unnecessary*) iteration of the data.

---

**UPDATE** *(to respond to changes in the question)*

> [...] In my mind, this made the use of iterators slightly redundant and more prone to human error

Using multiple iterators in parallel is not redundant.

Also, all programming is prone to human errors. You should generally use the algorithm that is most appropriate / correct, rather than consider *(very slight)* increases in potential programming error caused by increased complexity. Sure, if one algorithm is insanely complex, and another is easy, you likely want to use the easy one, *if* the improvement of the complex algorithm is not worth it. But there is a reason no one uses [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), even though it is super easy: Performance is really bad. In your case, the complexity of parallel iteration is minuscule.

Comparing use of multiple parallel iterators, vs. copying to `ArrayList`, which is more *redundant*? Copying to `ArrayList` is, because you end up iterating the data twice and you require more memory to do so.

Parallel iteration is the best solution to your problem. It uses the intended iteration mechanism of the provided `List`, without knowing the characteristics of the list. Iterating a `List` by index is inherently wrong. Lists (and other Collections) should always be iterated by the supplied [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) (or [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) or [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html)).

Also note that parallel iteration is sometimes the only option, e.g. in [merge-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), where you're not iterating the two inputs at the same speed.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I think about it, I had thought of that, but dismissed it because it seemed to me that declaring iterators individually, on top of looping and calling every single `next`was redundant. I will edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer. This will definitely change the way I see iterators and collections.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an answer to your question specifically but i feel you can benefit from this piece of information.

Since Java 1.6, there's a new type of collection, called [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) that has the fast random access like an array, but also has the fast add/remove at the ends.

`LinkedList` still wins at add/remove in the middle if the list.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had just gone through the [Collection interface tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html), but I now realize it didn't mention every collection *implementation*, I didn't remember there was such a thing as `ArrayDequeue`.

Comment: Unfortunately `ArrayDeque` doesn't support random access. (Yet.)

Comment: @Stuart Right, wasn't aware. But [looks like it's on the way](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2014-February/024947.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use iterators on LInkedLists and index for array:

```
    Iterator<Integer> i1 = listOne.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> i2 = listTwo.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < combined.length; i++) {
        combined[i] = i1.next() + i2.next();
    }
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid (`In my mind, this made the use of iterators slightly redundant and more prone to human error`). But Andreas pointed out that I didn't need necessarily need to avoid it.