# Is it possible to get the index of ArrayList<Object> when using Java8 Streams?

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to Java 8 lambdas and streams. For practice, i'm trying to "translate" some methods from a school project into lambdas/streams when possible.
Here it's the old method.

As you can see, i need to give to discard method a int, which is the number of the first playable card into the hand of the player.

```
public Card autoPlay(Card flipped) {
    for (int i = 0; i < super.getHand().size(); i++) {
        if (super.getHand().get(i).isCompatible(flipped)) { //check if card from hand is compatible with flipped card (same number or color)
            return (this.discard(i)); //remove from hand and returns it
        }
    }
    return null; //if any compatible card found
}
```

So far, the new version of my method is:

```
public Card newAutoPlay(Card flipped){
   return super.getHand().stream().filter(card -> card.isCompatible(flipped)).findFirst().get();

}
```

I found out how to get the first compatible card, but not how to get it's index... I read about IntStreams (and using the size of the list as a range), but i don't understand how to use it in this particular case.

Is it possible to achieve what i'm trying to do, or it's not a good idea to do this?

EDIT: After exploring the question, using streams in this case brings too much complexity and not enough readability for solving this simple problem. So i've choose to a for loop. Also some other changes, but the core idea remains the same. Thanks all for helping.

```
@Override
public String play(Uno unoGame) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean found = false;

    for (i = 0; i < super.getHand().size() && !found; i++) {
        found = super.getHand().get(i).isCompatible(unoGame.getFlippedCard());
    }

    return found ? "play " + i : "draw";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a concise way to iterate over a stream with indices in Java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8)

Comment: Beware that `findFirst().get()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if there's no compatible card.

Comment: findFirst() returns an empty Optional (null) if stream is empty. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Comment: Yes, but `get()` throws an exception if the Optional is empty.

Comment: @TanguyLabradorRuiz No, it does not.  It returns an empty Optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one liner:

```
   IntStream.range(0,getHand()::size).filter(i -> super.getHand().get(i).isCompatible(flipped))
                .mapToObj(Integer::new).findFirst().map(this::discard).orElse(null);
```

It's necessary to `mapToObj` because the `map` function on an `Optional` of type `int` doesn't exist. Sadly, java lacks native support for pairs which would make this less ugly. It could them "stream with index". Keep something in mind though: Streams are meant to be infinite and thus have no index.

Comment: Why not use `.boxed()` instead of `.mapToObj`?

Comment: It didn't occur to me. You're choice

Comment: My final code for solving this: http://paste.awesom.eu/cIt0&ln

I dropped the idea of using streams. But thank you for your example, it was very instructive, but i found it not enough readable, and over complex for that simple operation.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following solution to your existing code using Java 8 lambdas which requires to change the signature of `discard(int index)` to `discard(Card card)`, assuming `Card` does implement `equals(Object obj)` and `hashCode()`:

```
public Card autoPlay(Card flipped) {
    Optional<Card> card = getHand().stream()
            .filter(flipped::isCompatible)
            .findFirst();
    card.ifPresent(this::discard);
    return card.orElse(null);
}

private void discard(Card card) {
    // your code removing the first matching card from your hand
}
```

Instead of returning `null` you may consider changing the signature of `Card autoPlay(Card flipped)` to `Optional<Card> autoPlay(Card flipped)`.