# How to get index of findFirst() in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
ArrayList <String> entries = new ArrayList <String>();

entries.add("0");
entries.add("1");
entries.add("2");
entries.add("3");

String firstNotHiddenItem = entries.stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.equals("2"))
                    .findFirst()
                    .get();
```

I need to know what is the index of that first returned element, since I need to edit it inside of entries `ArrayList`. As far as I know `get()` returns the value of the element, not a reference. Should I just use

```
int indexOf(Object o)
```

instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't in a straightforward way - streams process elements without context of where they are in the stream.

However, if you're prepared to take the gloves off...

```
int[] position = {-1};

String firstNotHiddenItem = entries.stream()
        .peek(x -> position[0]++)  // increment every element encounter
        .filter("2"::equals)
        .findFirst()
        .get();

System.out.println(position[0]); // 2
```

The use of an `int[]`, instead of a simple `int`, is to circumvent the "effectively final" requirement; the *reference* to the array is *constant*, only its *contents* change.

Note also the use of a method reference `"2"::equals` instead of a lambda `e -> e.equals("2")`, which not only avoids a possible NPE (if a stream element is `null`) and more importantly looks *way* cooler.

---

A more palatable (less hackalicious) version:

```
AtomicInteger position = new AtomicInteger(-1);

String firstNotHiddenItem = entries.stream()
        .peek(x -> position.incrementAndGet())  // increment every element encounter
        .filter("2"::equals)
        .findFirst()
        .get();

position.get(); // 2
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Simple and elegant and does exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: You also need to initialize the variable `position` in the 2nd variant w/ `-1`. `AtomicInteger position = new AtomicInteger(-1);`

Comment: dears actually I have a similar need but with some difference,I have Strin val={1,2,3,4,5} i want to have an index of element in the original array, i.e. i need to know which element index of String[] val was "3" then I store element address for example val[2] was "3" Without if and just with java8

Comment: @milad this code will give you what you want.

Comment: dear @Bohemian i try this code but it just return a number of counter please assume I have array:
 int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5,6,..,15,...,20},
 I want every element was arr[I] % 3 == 0 then i should insert in the correspond String[] strArray for example :
arr={1,2,3,4,5,6,..,15,...,20} 
i must to have strArray={"1","2","Test",...,"Test","16","17","18","19","20"} ,Tnx

Comment: @milad `List<String> out = IntStream.of(intArray).mapToObj(n -> n % 3 == 0 ? "Test" : String.valueOf(n)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 20):

You can get the index of an element using an `IntStream` like:

```
int index = IntStream.range(0, entries.size())
                     .filter(i -> "2".equals(entries.get(i)))
                     .findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

But you should use the `List::indexOf` method which is the preferred way, because it's more concise, more expressive and computes the same results.

Comment: The key difference between `List.indexOf` and using a stream with `filter` and `findFirst` is that `indexOf` uses the `equals` method of the class of the elements of the list, while the stream approach allows you to search based on potentially complex predicates that are not related to elements´ *equality*.

Answer (score 1):

This will work using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) with Java 8 or above.

```
int firstIndex = ListIterate.detectIndex(entries, "2"::equals);
```

If you use a `MutableList`, you can simplify the code as follows:

```
MutableList<String> entries = Lists.mutable.with("0", "1", "2", "3");
int firstIndex = entries.detectIndex("2"::equals);
```

There is also a method to find the last index.

```
int lastIndex = entries.detectLastIndex("2"::equals);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Comment: Seems a little surprising / asymmetric that you need to use `MutableList` to get the simplification.  I get that the first example takes a normal `List`.  Is there / what's the reason for only being able to implement detectIndex on MutableList?

Comment: The method `detectIndex` is available on `OrderedIterable` so this works with immutable types as well. I guess I just decided to use `MutableList` when I answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use `indexOf("2")` instead. As you might have noticed, any stream based solution has a higher complexity, without providing any benefit.

In this specific situation, there is no significant difference in performance, but overusing streams can cause dramatic performance degradation, e.g. when using `map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(object)).map(e -> e.getValue())` instead of a simple `map.get(object)`.

The collection operations may utilize their known structure while most stream operation imply a linear search. So genuine collection operations are preferable.

Of course, if there is no collection operation, like when your predicate is not a simple equality test, the Stream API may be the right tool. As shown in “[Is there a concise way to iterate over a stream with indices in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18552005/2711488)”, the solution for any task involving the indices works by using the indices as starting point, e.g. via `IntStream.range`, and accessing the list via `List.get(int)`. If the source in not an array or a random access `List`, there is no equally clean and efficient solution. Sometimes, a loop might turn out to be the simplest and most efficient solution.