# Char array to Map using Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I've a char array:

```
private char[] chars = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890-_".toCharArray();
```

I want get a `Map` when key is char symbol and value is index this char in array. Like this:

```
{q=0, w=1,....}
```

I want use a `Stream api`:

```
Map<Character, Integer> charToInt = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, chars.length)
```

But I do not understand what to do next

Comment: In your case method like `zipWithIndex` would be useful. Unfortunately Java's streams don't support anything similar yet. Have a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8). It might give you a hint what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go by this way and use the `String` instead of its `charArray` :

```
private String s = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890-_";
```

And then create the `Map` like this :

```
Map<Character, Integer> charToInt = s.chars()
                                     .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c, c -> s.indexOf(c)));
```

So create a `Map` wit as `key` the `char`, and as `value` its index in the `String`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with `IntStream`:

```
Map<Character, Integer> charToInt = 
                    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, chars.length-1)
                             .mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(i)))
                             .collect(Collectors
                                      .toMap(i -> Character.valueOf(chars[i]), i -> i));
```

Answer (score 1):

> **P.S.** We have previous similar answer as I was writing my own. But I
>   keep it as alternative, using Pair class.

To solve this problem, you have to implement `Pair` class or use any available implementation (as example I give you easiest one):

```
final class Pair {
    private char ch;
    private int pos;

    public Pair(char ch, int pos) {
        this.ch = ch;
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public char getChar() {
        return ch;
    }

    public int getPos() {
        return pos;
    }
}
```

Then you could use streams to solve your problem:

```
Map<Character, Integer> res = IntStream.range(0, chars.length)
         .mapToObj(pos -> new Pair(chars[pos], pos))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getChar, Pair::getPos));
```