# How to increment a "number" in a Java 8 lambda expression in a loop?

Tags: java

I have the following problem. I have an integer position which starts at 1 and increments every time a specific person from a txt is found at a specific position in an xml. If I use the classic iteration with the foreach `for (PersonMatchInfo pmi : personMatchInfo)` it works, but my senior asked me to do with the Java 8 `foreach` and this type of iteration works only with final variables. How can I increment the integer in the new Java 8 loop? Thank you.

```
int position = 1;
personMatchInfo.forEach(pmi ->{

                    if (!stopwatch1.isStarted()) {
                        stopwatch1.start();
                    } else if (stopwatch1.isStarted()) {

                    }

                    if (pmi.getPersonName().equals(e.getValue())) {

                        positionMap.put(position, positionMap.get(position) + 1);
                        break;

                    } else {

                        position++;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: by telling your  senior: "that is not a reasonable request, it needlessly takes up time, is more complex and it is less readable. And I do not know how to do it because final blah blah blah, can you please help me!?"

Comment: He told me to use this type of loop because it "reduces" time a little and stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a concise way to iterate over a stream with indices in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8)

Comment: Agreed, it's a very silly request from your senior. And if they don't believe you when you say so, you can show them this comment and at least you'll have the strength of the word of a few strangers on the Internet.

Comment: Which is simply wrong, evidenced by this very conversation which definitely takes more time than leaving the already working code in place.

Comment: (It would not reduce the time consumed by the code - it would not perform better than a classical foreach loop.)

Comment: Ask your senior if he is familiar with the term "premature optimization".

Comment: @Fildor Can we add "K.I.S.S" while we're at it?

Comment: @Bilkokuya I think we could even find some more if we tried.

Comment: I think stopwatch logic should not belong to the loop, place it outside, then it's not really clear what kind of map you are building (perhaps a unit test might be more self- explanatory next time). Also I would not just rely on what a senior says, just because Java 8 has streams does not mean they have to be used all the time, I am not sure it would be very performant. If you don't really want to do an imperative iteration try with a tail-recursion instead, it might work better

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `AtomicInteger`, and `incrementAndGet` method on it.

Other solution would be `int[] position = new int[]{1};`

and incrementing `position[0]++;`

Comment: It works with the array but it is reducing the runtime whatsoever. Still the same. :(

Comment: what do you mean by reducing the runtime? You will not gain performance by switching from for_each loop, to collection.forEach

Comment: Right now i am trying to reduce the duration of the run in my code. My senior gave me the "hint" to use lambda foreachs because they are java 8 based and stuff.

Comment: awful hint. Try sampling/profiling your code with jvisualvm

Comment: The atomic integer reduced the runtime duration with 2 minutes.

Comment: `org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableInt` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static variable :

```
public class Poubelle {

    private static int position = 1;

    public static void setPosition (List<PersonMatchInfo> listPersonMatchInfo) {

          listPersonMatchInfo.forEach(pmi -> {
          pmi.setPosition(position++);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ironically, using a static int is what worked for me. I had a pair of nested lambda functions, and I needed to pass on the count of the inner lambda function into its contents. Since the outer lambda function needed to re-set the variable to zero every time it ticked over, I just did a `position = 0;` (to use your example) before the inner lambda function. Haven’t yet tested, but intellisense is not having a hissy fit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you senior is asking you to use streams for collections.
Then use collection.stream.filter.count based on your logic  that will produce a long as the value and use it.

Comment: no the downvoter, but that sounds like an utter abuse of the `filter` method and only works by coincidence.

Comment: Thanks bro for your answer

Comment: I was initially thinking the same as Mark, and I think `map` `filter` `count` it's a perfectly valid case for counting instead of modifying a global state counter although I read the question again and I don't think a `count` operation is needed here as this is building a map with positions.

Answer (score 0):

*I know it is late, so I will just put it out here for future seekers.*
Here is how you can do it in a very simple way :

use  `indexOf(Object O)` property of collections

```
StringBuffer messageBody = new StringBuffer();    
List<VipObj> listOfAllVips = getResponse();
    listOfAllVipsLocal.forEach(vip -> {
                            messageBody.append("\n\t" + (listOfAllVipsLocal.indexOf(vip) + 1) + ". " + vip.getBaseUrl() + "\n");
                        });
```