# Inserting elements into map using streams

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, java-stream

I have a

```
List<String> lists;
```

I need to iterate through this lists and put in the `LinkedHashMap`. Normally I do it as below:

```
Map<Integer,String> listMap=new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(int pos=0;pos<lists.size();pos++){
    listMap.put(pos,lists.get(pos));
}
```

How can I do the above operation with streams?

Comment: You might as well have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). You you need to work with indexes it is probably better to use an old forEach loop. Streams  are not designed to support operations which involves indexes of the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Collectors.toMap` on a `Stream<Integer>` of the `List`'s indices:

```
Map<Integer,String> listMap =
   IntStream.range(0,lists.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                      lists::get,
                                      (a,b)->a,
                                      LinkedHashMap::new));
```

P.S., the output `Map` is a `Map<Integer,String>`, which fits the for loop in your question (unlike the specified `Map<Integer,List<String>>`, which doesn't, unless you change the input `List` from `List<String>` to `List<List<String>>`).

Comment: Any reason you preferred `Function.identity()` over `Function::identity` ?

Comment: @mks What do you think is the target type of `Function::identity`?

Comment: @mks Function.identity() returns an identity Function (which can also be expressed by the lambda expression i-> i). That's what was needed for generating the keys of the output map.

Comment: My bad, I got confused with multiple parameters with real method call vs. method reference.