# Take every nth. element out of an Array of Objects using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to solve little easy exercises with streams and I was wondering which way is the most efficient way to get a stream out of an `Person[]` but taking every second object.

```
Person[] myarr = {person1, person2, person3, person4, person5};
```

The output stream should consist of the objects `person1, person3, person5` Any good efficient ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a concise way to iterate over a stream with indices in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8)

Comment: The most efficient way is to write an ArraySpliterator that advances by N indices instead of one. The most simple way is to use an accompanying IntStream and filter out unwanted indicis, as suggested by @JB Nizet.

Comment: The expected output must have a pattern that is derivable mathematically for that which you forgot to mention in the question and then what you're looking for it to iterate over a stream with indices.

Comment: @Torben I don’t think that a custom Spliterator implementation gives a significant advantage over IntStream…map

Answer (score 2):

```
IntStream.range(0, myarr.length)
    .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
    .mapToObj(i -> myarr[i]);
```

Comment: I prefer `IntStream.range(0, (myarr.length+1)/2) .mapToObj(i -> myarr[i*2])`…