# JUnit 5: Accessing index inside ParameterizedTest

Tags: java, junit5

Consider this snippet:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"a", "b", "c"})
void test(final String line) {
    // code here
}
```

This will be an actual test, but for simplicity assume its purpose is to only print this:

```
Line 1: processed "a" successfully.
Line 2: processed "b" successfully.
Line 3: failed to process "c".
```

In other words, I want the index of the test values to be accessible **within** the test.
From what I found, `{index}` can be used outside the test to name it properly.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why would your tests need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if JUnit 5 currently supports this. A workaround could be to use `@MethodSource` and provide a `List<Argument>` matching your needs.

```
public class MyTest {

  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("methodSource")
  void test(final String input, final Integer index) {
    System.out.println(input + " " + index);
  }

  static Stream<Arguments> methodSource() {
    List<String> params = List.of("a", "b", "c");

    return IntStream.range(0, params.size())
      .mapToObj(index -> Arguments.arguments(params.get(index), index));
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I think we can let `methodSource` return `Stream<Arguments>`, and therefore there is no need to use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` at the end. This was tested using JUnit 5.7.0-M1 successfully.

Comment: And by the way, just found a Guava method (currently in beta) which can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42673873/459391.

Comment: you are right, this can be even simplified. I updated the answer. The Guava method looks promising

Comment: One technicality for future: Guava `mapWithIndex` uses `Long` indices rather than `Integer`.